How to set up YOLOv8 with PyTorch on Ubuntu 24.04 and NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti?
I'm trying to set up YOLOv8 with PyTorch on my system, but I'm encountering some issues. Here are my system specifications and the steps I've taken so far:
System specifications:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04  GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti CUDA version: 12.4 (installed with the NVIDIA driver)
Is there a recommended way to install YOLOv8 with PyTorch on Ubuntu 24.04 and CUDA 12.4? I want to make sure my RTX 3050 Ti is utilized properly for running YOLOv8. Any guidance on getting this setup to work correctly would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve done so far:
Installed the NVIDIA driver and confirmed the GPU is detected using nvidia-smi.
Installed CUDA 12.4, which is the version that came with my NVIDIA driver.
Installed Python 3.8 and pip.

I recommend creating a virtual enviroment for ultralytics and after activating it, in terminal use this command:
pip install ultralytics

this command will install all the required packages for yolo and i should mention that the version of cuda and pytorch it installs is different from what you have on your own system. Since this is in a virtual enviroment you don't have to worry about any changes to your system.
